# Android Writing to JSON file

Tags: android, json

Hey so I'm creating an Android app that allows users to vote.  The app reads a JSON file from a server.  This JSON file will be used to display the users' choice % after they are done answering questions.  So basically on ever question, I need it to display the users' choice % that is read from the JSON file from the server.

I am not sure how I would go about updating this JSON file from the server w/e a user votes on a specific question.  My thoughts on this was to first read the JSON file then add 1 if the choice was selected.  Then write to the JSON file to the server in order to update it.

Is this the correct approach in order to update this JSON file?

example of my JSON file:

```
    {
"polls": [
    {
        "count1": "0",
        "count2": "0",
        "count3": "0",
        "count4": "0",
        "count5": "0"
    },
    {   
        "count1": "0",
        "count2": "0",
        "count3": "0",
        "count4": "0",
        "count5": "0"
    },
    {
        "count1": "0",
        "count2": "0",
        "count3": "0",
        "count4": "0",
    }
]
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no problem with your approach but it 'll increase a bit overhead or parsing the data every time and sending all data to server each time. So if it possible to make the changes on server side and  can implement new service then it would be better to attach a unique id with each poll and send only three types of data

1 -   unique id of poll
2-    choice selected by the user 
3-    user id /IMEI (optional)

just put the logic on serer side to increment the poll by 1 as per "choice selected by the user"

Even in your if two phones make the request at time then it may create problem. or if as there are number of users so user who fetches data earlier but due to some issue like network latency 'll over-wirte the result of users who poll in between.